# Can i create a subclass object for a dynamic Array List super class type object?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass, dynamic-arrays

If i wanted to use a Dynamic Array List which is initializing class Worker can i add sub-classes that extend the Worker class and try to fill them with data like the following test class?.. whenever i try calling a certain function that one of the sub-classes have i get an error , I need to call these functions so how can i do it correctly?

```
    public class Worker extends Person {
        private int id;

        Worker() {
        }

        Worker(int i) {
            id = i;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + "ID: " + id + " ";
        }
    }


    public class HourlyWorker extends Worker implements Annual {
        private double rate;
        private double AnnualPayment;
        private double percentageIncrease;

        HourlyWorker() {
        }

        HourlyWorker(double r) {
            rate = r;
        }

        public double getAnnualPay(double Annualpayment) {
            return Annualpayment = rate * 52 * 40;
        }

        public double getRate() {
            return rate;
        }

        public void setRate(double rate) {
            this.rate = rate;
        }

        public double getAnnualPayment() {
            return AnnualPayment;
        }

        public void setAnnualPayment(double AnnualPayment) {
            this.AnnualPayment = AnnualPayment;
        }

        public double getpercentageIncrease() {
            return percentageIncrease;
        }

        public void setpercentageIncrease(double percentageIncrease) {
            this.percentageIncrease = percentageIncrease;
        }


        public void increasePayment(double r) {
            increasePayR(r);
        }

        public double increasePayR(double r) {
            return rate = (AnnualPayment + getAnnualPay(r) * percentageIncrease) / 2080;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Your rate : " + rate + " ";
        }
    }


    public class SalariedWorker extends Worker implements Annual {
        private double salary;
        private double AnnualPayment;
        private double percentageIncrease;

        SalariedWorker() {
        }

        SalariedWorker(double s) {
            salary = s;
        }

        public double getAnnualPay(double Annualpayment) {
            return Annualpayment = salary * 12;
        }

        public void increasePayment(double r) {
            increasePayS(r);
        }

        public double increasePayS(double r) {
            return salary = (AnnualPayment + getAnnualPay(r) * percentageIncrease) / 12;
        }

        public double getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

        public void setSalary(double salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public double getAnnualPayment() {
            return AnnualPayment;
        }

        public void setAnnualPayment(double AnnualPayment) {
            this.AnnualPayment = AnnualPayment;
        }

        public double getpercentageIncrease() {
            return percentageIncrease;
        }

        public void setpercentageIncrease(double percentageIncrease) {
            this.percentageIncrease = percentageIncrease;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return " ";
        }
    }


    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);
            ArrayList<Worker> Worker1 = new ArrayList<Worker>();

            Worker1.add(new SalariedWorker());// is it alright to create a subclass object here?
            Worker1.add(new SalariedWorker(1000.0));// index 1
            Worker1.add(new HourlyWorker());// index 2
            Worker1.add(new HourlyWorker(100.0));// index 3

            System.out.println("Enter your monthly salary: ");
            double salary = prompt.nextDouble();
            Worker1.get(0).getSalary(salary);//gets me an error
            System.out.println("Enter your hourly rate: ");
            double HourlyRate = prompt.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter the Percentage Increase for a Salaried worker: ");
            double PercentIncreaseS = prompt.nextDouble();
            Worker1.get(0).getpercentageIncrease(PercentIncreaseS);//gets me an error
            System.out.println("Your Increased payment is: ");
            System.out.println("Enter the Percentage Increase for an Hourly worker: ");
            double PercentIncreaseH = prompt.nextDouble();
        }
    }
```

Comment: We'll be able to help a lot better if you include full details on the actual error, and try formatting your code a little.

Comment: yes you can create a run time object(like its the only place you want to use) but if you need to use it  multiple multiple time u must declare it and for error thing you must provide complete error from your console

Comment: and getsalary dosen't have any arguments

Comment: try worker.get(0),getsalary()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because the `Worker` class does not have a `getSalary()` method.

You need to cast the objects in the list to the appropriate sub-class type.

For example:

```
SalariedWorker sw = (SalariedWorker) Worker1.get(0);
sw.getSalary(salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with below code fragment is:

```
ArrayList<Worker> Worker1 = new ArrayList<Worker>();
Worker1.get(0).getSalary(salary);
```

get will return you the `abstraction` which doesn't have the `getSalary(salary)` method. All you have to do is to cast each with respective implementation class and the invoke the method on it.
Ex:

```
SalariedWorker sw = (SalariedWorker)Worker1.get(0);
```